# Translate a LINQ query to LINQJS

Tags: linq, linq.js

How would you translate this query:

```
var groups = visibleDateRange.select((date, index) => new { Date = date, Index = index })
                                     .GroupBy(p => p.Index / 3);
```

to a javascript linqJS query?

All the linqJS samples are super simple... no real life stuff.

My problem is how can I return the anonymous object with Date + Index from the select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var groups = Enumerable.From(visibleDateRange)
    .Select("date, index => { Date: date, Index: index }")
    .GroupBy("p => p.Index / 3")
    .ToArray();
```

I used the lambda syntax to define the selectors but you can certainly use regular javascript functions and whatnot.

What you want to get from this is that what you return in your functions is just regular javascript. You're returning an anonymous object with `Date` and `Index` members, you create a javascript object with `Date` and `Index` members.  It's not too different.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for taking time. I am still too much of a static guy hehe I just could not see how the 'selector' is resolved because its a full string. So linqjs is really parsing the syntax of the selectors? Thats crazy that linqjs knows that inside the .Select("stringhere") is actually an anonymous object or object literal.

Comment: Linq.js does some "magic" when you provide string selectors. Namely, it is parsed as if it was a function. So the syntax used to define the function looks a lot like a C# lambda. If you were to look at the code, it's essentially doing an `eval()` on the RHS of the lambda.